# Override default proxy creation behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, aspect, proxies

I have a project with the following xml configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" order="-2147483648"
                      proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

Now I have a Bean in particular that I would like to proxy using interfaces. I tried the following configuration:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class MySpecialBean implements SomeInterface {
  @Transactional
  public void ...
}
```

Regardless of having the @Scope annotation or not I get the same CGLib error complaining about not having a constructor with no arguments (the bean has constructor injected dependecies).

Is is possible to override the default proxy creation behavior?

Comment: Your bean doesn’t implement an interface then how an interface based proxy can be created?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that part to the question, my bean actually has a interface.

Comment: The `@Scope` is only for scoped proxies not for regular proxying. So for that the settings from the configuration apply.